# Question about permutations and cycles (Groups and Symmetries)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $a = (123)(456)$ be in $S_{10}$. Find a permutation $b$ in $A_{10}$ such that the disjoint cycle form of does not contain any $3$ cycles and $a$ is in $\langle b \rangle$.

Attempt: I'm assuming that $b$ must also assign each integer to the following one in each of it's cycles (or part of a cycle) containing $1$ to $6$. But I'm not sure how to rebracket $a$ so that $b$ doesn't have a cycle of the form (###) while some other element in it's generated group sends $3$ back to $1$ and $6$ back to $4$. Is this right?

Comment: The last sentence in the first paragraph makes no sense. Please complete the sentence so we can understand what you are asking.

Comment: Care to translate the last part @bernard ?

Comment: could it be $a$ is in $\langle b \rangle$

Comment: Oh yeah, looking at the code it is!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see what you mean… Could you explain more?

Comment: I didn't know what the question was, but looking at the code he want to find b without 3-cycle so that a is in <b>. the problem is mathjax deletes everything that apears after < so we couldn't read the question

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, consider the permutation $(142536)(78)$ when you square it you get $(123)(456)$